# Error filling print... Error preparing statement for executing the report query : select * from tabla_tb - IREPORT

Tags: java, mysql, ireport

tengo inconvenientes al generar mi reporte por ireport, mi tipo de dato con el cual uso la condicion es datetime, este es el query que utilizo:

```
select * from cabecera_central where  date(time_ingreso_final) = '2018-11-06'
```

Y cuando le coloco un parametro del mismo tipo de dato: me bota el mismo error, eh tratado de ponerle otro tipo de dato al parametro sin embargo me bota el mismo error:

```
`Error filling print... Error preparing statement for executing the report query :   select * from cabecera_central where  date(time_ingreso_final)= '?'
```

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query :   select * from cabecera_central where  date(time_ingreso_final)= '?'        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:372)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1112)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:689)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:87)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)      at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)      at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1408)      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1421)      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setNull(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1686)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setTimestamp(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:598)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:569)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:399)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter$1.visit(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:332)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter$QueryParameter.accept(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:157)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.visitQueryParameters(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:646)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:317)      ... 15 more  
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algun buen samaritano que ilumine mi camino? Gracias de antemano.

**A. Cedano** , te confirmo que mi tipo de dato es DATETIME , enla columna time_ingreso_final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te comento que cuando coloco este query:

```
select * from cabecera_central  where time_ingreso_final ='2018-11-06' order by time_ingreso_final = '2018-11-06'
```

me bota el resultado no deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando utilizo este query

```
select * from cabecera_central where  date(time_ingreso_final) BETWEEN '2018-11-06' and '2018-11-07' ORDER BY time_ingreso_final DESC
```

, si me filtra la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por eso es que coloco el date (columna) en la consulta, ahora, me mencionaste que en el parametro de el ireport debo colocarle el signo de exclamacion adelante de la P?, La verdad eso no creo que sea el problema porque el mismo ireport le bota asi un parametro, ademas,cuando le coloco el signo de exclamacion, me sale esto: THE DOCUMENT HAS NO PAGES. por cierto, en donde le selecciono el tipo de dato del parametro, es datetime, como en mi db:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando lo colocas aparece Time.

Comment: Tu consulta preparada no debería tener el marcador rodeado por comillas simples, prueba a quitarle las comillas alrededor de `' ?'`. Luego, el parámetro parece que es del tipo  `Time`, no del tipo `Date`. Por otra parte, en vez de imágenes, comparte el texto del código que estás usando.

Comment: Cuando se usan consultas preparadas, en el reporte, el párametro debe escribirse así: `$P!{name_parameter}`, en tu caso, debe estar así: `WHERE date(time_ingreso_final)=$P!{fecha}` ... aunque hay más cosas raras en tu consulta misma, por ejemplo, ¿esa columna no es del tipo `DATETIME` en la tabla? ¿por qué haces una conversión con `date`?